# Trapping ctrl-c using signal handler but could not exit application due to an infinite loop in callback thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

Trapping ctrl-c using signal handler but could not exit application due to an infinite loop in callback thread.

I have a signal handler to trap ctrl-c and in the handler I do some action and do a exit(0);
But in my application, if any callback thread is running infinite loop, I just could not exit the application even after ctrl-c.

I tried pthread_kill, pthread_exit, pthread_cancel but nothing worked.

FYI, I dont have the flexibility to flag the while(1) loops cause I have too many. I just want to exit the application, please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I have too many" while loops.  It ought to be simple to replace every `while (1)` with `while  (!quit_flag)`.  That might even be as simple as search-and-replace.

Comment: here for your understanding I said while(1) but in fact I have too many while loops which run until a condition is satisfied and that conditional flag is modified by the callback thread.

Comment: Did you register any exit handlers (using `atexit()`)? If not I do not see any reason why `exit()` should not end the program, assuming it was called ... ;-)

Comment: that's the mystery yet to be solved.

Comment: The thread library registers `atexit()` hooks.

Comment: You could use `gdb` to attach to the process unwilling to stop and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`_exit(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/exit.2.html) instead, it doesn't run exit hooks.